# Why does the floating point representation of 0.1 end in 1?

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee-754, single-precision

I've been writing a decimal to single-precision IEEE754 floating-point converter, and I found a few discrepancies with numbers like 0.1 and 0.2

Let's take 0.1, the first step would be converting it into a simple binary representation (multiplying the fractional part by 2 and taking the integral part)
This gives me a well-known recurring binary pattern (001100110011...)

The final binary representation of 0.1 (up to 26-bits) is  0 . 00 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110.

To fit it into a 32-bit floating-point number, the next step is to normalize it by shifting the decimal point 4 times to the right, removing the leading 1.,  and truncating it to 23 bits. This leaves me with 10011001100110011001100. Most programming languages give me 10011001100110011001101 (with the last bit 1 instead of 0). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Carry? Rounding? What is the actual floating-point value of your `10011001100110011001100` versus the others `10011001100110011001101`, which is closer to the actual `0.1`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the actual value of my number is 0.0999999940395355224609375, which is apparently further from the actual 0.1 than with the last bit flipped. I still have no idea _how_ it gets flipped though. 0011 is the infinitely recurring sequence here, so logically 00 should come after 11, not 01.

Comment: Show the code you are using to do these calculations. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 4):

> ... removing the leading 1., and truncating it to 23 bits.

Wrong operation: *round*, not *truncate*. Wrong order of operations - round, then remove the leading 1.

> ... still have no idea how it gets flipped though

The infinite exact binary answer *rounded* to the closest `float`.

---

With common [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), the significand is 24-bit<sup>*1</sup>.  Conversion of values with more than 24-bits is usually a *round*<sup>*2</sup>, not truncate.  The remaining bits were 110_0110_...

```
        123 4567 8901 2345 6789 0123 4
0 . 00 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 ...
        ^----------------------------^
0 . 00 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1 rounded
         10 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1 encoded 23-bits
```

The rounding happens before the leading bit is removed as part of the encoding as the most significant bit place may change.

---

Notes:

```
0.000110011001100110011001100           (binary) = 0.0999999940395355224609375000 (decimal)
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110... (binary) = 0.1                            (decimal)
0.000110011001100110011001101 (closer)  (binary) = 0.1000000014901161193847656250 (decimal)
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> Most significant 1 bit implied, 23-bits explicitly coded.
<sup>*2</sup> Round to nearest, ties to even.